# Layout design issue

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in the layout design in android studio, in android studio I set 720x1280 in the design preview option. Its the first image. But when i build the apk and install it in the device, the same activity looks like the second image. Its like it's cut.

I need that in the first image, the blank space "expands" because i need to put the title long across in the second screen. The sentence is "Ingrese fecha de vencimiento" but only shows "Ingrese fecha de" .

How can i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a constraint to attach the right side of the TextView that says "Ingrese Fecha de vencimiento" to the right side of the container window.  This will allow that TextView to expand and contract as the container expands and contracts.  You should just have to click on the right side of the container and drag toward the right side of the TextView to create the constraint.